# How to solve a system of equations with only integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

$a+2y = 320$

$2b+3y = 320$

$3c+4y = 320$

And a, b, c, and y are all integers.

How do I find all possible solutions, if any?

Comment: @MatthewConroy Nothing, I don't know how to approach the problem, that's why I asked.

Comment: Albert: You should add context to help others help you.  Where did you encounter this problem?  Is it a homework problem, or a problem you are working on to teach yourself something? Why do you want to know how to solve this system? Answers to these questions will be very helpful.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Doesn't seem relevant, but okay... I'm programming a grid that displays images. Either 1 image with a widthxheight of axa and a cushioned region between the edges of the screen with width or length y. The 2x2 grid has images with widthxheight bxb and I want the cushioning constant. "y". The 3x3 grid has images with widthxheight cxc. Since I'm dealing with pixels on a screen it must be integers because I can't light up half of a pixel or a third of a pixel.

Comment: Albert: Thanks for the info.  The relevance is that we are trying to live in a society.  You want something from the helpful people on this site, so it is only kind and fair that you be forthcoming with information about your problem, especially when asked.  Is Ross's answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the last equation, $c$ must be a multiple of $4$ and $y \equiv 2 \pmod 3$, from the second $y$ must be even and $b \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, and from the first, $a$ must be even.  You can choose any one variable subject to these constraints and solve for the rest.

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou very much!